# Eclipse: how to differentiate/distinguish different open workspaces

Tags: eclipse, organization, workspace

I will need to use multiple *workspaces* for a recent project. Each *workspace* might consist of 10 or more projects.

When I'm switching between various applications and different Eclipse instances (for the multiple *workspaces*), I want to be able to distinguish a given *workspace* easily without having to spend 5 seconds to know from the open file, etc.

What facilities are available to quickly know which workspace I'm in ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Virtual desktops might help here.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Windows Vista 64-bit version(HOME PREMIUM).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `-showlocation` command line argument when starting Eclipse. This shows the current workspace name in the window's title. You can also put the argument in the `eclipse.ini` file.

Comment: It would be nice to have an indication in the Dock on OS X (just saying :-).

Answer (score 7):

You can also add your own window title in:

```
eclipse preferences > workspace > workspace name (shown in window title)
```

Explained here: http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/show-workspace-location-title

Answer (score 3):

-showlocation is great, but it only changes the text at the end of the title bar, so it's often not visible in the taskbar.

If you want to change the beginning of the title bar, which shows the current Perspective, you can use Window -> Save Perspective As... and the new title will be visible in the Taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use also the OS for this to setup different workspaces, with diff, background or so. Where you have in each workspace a Eclipse running, with a diff workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create different working sets in the same workspace. The you only need one eclipse and switch between working sets in 1 sec depending on the mouse speed :)