# How can I debug two projects in eclipse at the same time?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two projects: consle and android project. I want to compare the values of variables because the same code (as I think) gives different results. I have to find the error.
If I press the F6 button the state changes just in one project.
Is it possible to switch the debugging project on the fly?

Comment: Running two instances of Eclipse is the only way, AFAIK.

Comment: check out the ans and comment of beworker it may help you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put breakpoints in both projects and launch them in debug mode.

Switch to "Debug" perspective and find "Debug" *view* there. You will see a list of active debug sessions with their respective call stacks. You can click on every debug step of every debug session and Eclipse will open that step in code editor. "Variables" view will also be updated.

Comment: how to select two project at a time for debug mode

Comment: You launch two projects in debug mode one after another. They both will appear in "Debug" view, where you can switch between them by clicking on a call stack node. "Variables" view will show debug values for one project at time. By switching between call stack nodes of different projects you can see values for those projects and compare them.

Comment: This is the best answer. I found it right before I wrote this message. Anyway. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

- Run both projects
- Open console-window
- On the right in the console-window there is a button that says "Display Selected Console"
- Switch between your projects console-windows

Answer (score -1):

In one instance of Eclipse, you can't run two processes at once. 
 You could have two Eclipses open for each project.

For Android Development, here's some Debugging Documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html

Comment: Yes you can as explained above

Answer (score -1):

Open two Eclipse instances that's the only way.

The following link can be of some help-

[Can you have 2 completely independent instances of Eclipse running at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930911/can-you-have-2-completely-independent-instances-of-eclipse-running-at-the-same-t)

Comment: Yes you can as explained above

Answer (score -2):

**it's impossible to do that.**

Maybe you should take the help of **Debug Log**, as you say, the code is the same,
then the log output should be the same,too.

Use Debug(F6) is usually inefficiency.

Comment: you can debug from single instance as explained above