# Debug two different project at same time

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, xdebug

I am starting to set up Xdebug with sublime-text2.
In my case, I have two different applications those are integrated as one. Let's named A and B.

I have XDebug set up for the project B and I can start to debug.
From the A site there is a link to the site B, so I want start debuging the application A and when I click the link to the application B, continue debugging the application B.

Is that possible?

I am going to try this approach
[How can I debug two projects in eclipse at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395243/how-can-i-debug-two-projects-in-eclipse-at-the-same-time)

but I coudn't find the sublime way, so in the mind time maybe some of you, dear reader, can point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

I have only seen to set one url by project.

**EDIT**:
I have configured the xdebug sublime plugin as by project and when I launch the debugger from the A site, the debug session is launched on both sides. I can see the breakpoint at the B site from the debug session at project A. 
But when I follow a link at site A, the

/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=devwebsite_ide_key

parameter is lost so the debug session is detached in the browser even if at sublime the debug session is still running.

Any ideas?